# How to maintain state of global vaiable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, static-members

Hi I have script below: Basically I have a navigation anchors "next" and "prev" which increments or decrements currentDate to navigate between days. This means variable currentDate cannot refresh once the page is load. This variable should be like static variable which should maintain its state, however when ajax call comes back this variable is updated each time to new Date().

```
<script>
var currentDate = new Date();

$(document).ready(function() {  
//ajax call to retrieve some values from the server
 });
</script>
```

Is it possible to declare a global variable which doesn't refresh with each ajax call? Or is it better to get the updated date from the server in this situation? Or am I handling this situation wrongly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global javascript variable would not normally reset to "**new Date()**" simply because an AJAX call returns. It **would** reset if the page is refreshed. Are you sure there isn't a **windows.location** call or something else in your AJAX return handler that refreshes the page?

Comment: You're right, I  had to remove href attribute from the anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

`currentDate` will not change with each ajax call.  If it does, then either it's being set somewhere else or the page itself is being refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

State is not maintained between browser reloads. But there are a bunch of possibilites to persist your data, though, and read them on page load again. You could store the data:

- using JavaScript local storage (only for HTML5)
- by writing to and reading from cookies (like most websites do)
- by using the windows pageName as a data store. This is, in my opinion, the most creepy solution :-)
- by using a server to persist the stuff (like applications like Gmail do)

On each of these topics plenty of documentation is available out there.